# Solution builds fine in Visual Studio 2015, but fails in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I recently switched to using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. My solution builds just fine in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, but when I try to build in 2017 I get an error.

Output window says:

> At
>   C:\Repos\...\MyProject\_CreateNewNuGetPackage\DoNotModify\New-NuGetPackage.ps1:1206
>   char:7
>
> "Could not determine where NuGet Package was created to. This
>   typically means that an error occurred while NuGet.exe was packing
>   it..."

Things I tried:

- updating all Nuget packages to most recent version
- deleting the solution and pulling it down from git again
- Restoring Nuget packages ("All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore")

Are there still some bugs in Visual Studio 2017, or do I need to update something with Nuget?

Comment: It looks like you have custom build tooling for your project (I'm guessing https://newnugetpackage.codeplex.com), if so, try updating that or explain what you tried to accomplish with that tool.

Answer (score 0):

> At C:\Repos...\MyProject_CreateNewNuGetPackage\DoNotModify\New-NuGetPackage.ps1:1206 char:7
>   "Could not determine where NuGet Package was created to. This typically means that an error occurred while NuGet.exe was packing it..."

According to the error log, you can check the [NuGetPackage.ps1](https://newnugetpackage.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1656070) file, you will noticed that the parameter of $ProjectFilePath or $NuSpecFilePath is needed.

Besides, in the [Visual Studio 2017 release note](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes):

> MSBuild support for .NET Core projects, with a simplified csproj
>   project format that makes it easier to edit by hand, without the need
>   to unload the project.

And in Visual Studio 2017, the NuGet 4.0 will be shipped as a part of Visual Studio. So when you have custom build task in the your project, you need to check the NuGet version and the parameter of ProjectFilePath or NuSpecFilePath.
If above could not help you, you can share your project file to us, we will follow it up.

Hope this can help you.